# Contact name append in Account name

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to write a trigger in which I have an Account named 'John' when I create Its contact named 'Smith' then the account name automatically gets updated to John Smith.

```
trigger tt on Contact (before insert)    
{  
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();  
    set<id> accountIdList = new Set<id>();  
    for(contact con : Trigger.new)  
    {  
        accountIdList.add(con.accountid);  
    }  
        Map<Id,account> mapVar = new Map<Id,account>([SELECT id,name
                                                  FROM account WHERE Id IN : accountIdList]);

for(contact cont : Trigger.new)
{
    contact con = new contact();
    {
        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.id = mapVar.get(cont.accountid).id;
        acct.name = mapVar.get(cont.accountid).name + '-' +con.lastname;
        accList.add(acct);
    }
    }
    update accList;
}

}
```

Comment: So whats happening now ?

Comment: the trigger is saved but its not working John-null is coming...I mean contact value is not coming in Account

Comment: you need to  concatenate contact name with account name when contact is created. right??

Comment: @DOMINICEDWARD right

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this? You could do this using process builder as well, no code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the **con.lastname** variable which you are using. I am not sure why you are initializing newly inside the for loop when you already have variable from Trigger.new iterator.

**It should be**

```
cont.lastname
```

**The modified code will be:**

```
trigger tt on Contact (before insert)    
{  
    set<id> accountIdList = new Set<id>();  
    for(contact con : Trigger.new)  
    {  
        accountIdList.add(con.accountid);  
    }  

    Map<Id,account> mapVar = new Map<Id,account>([SELECT id,name
                                                  FROM account WHERE Id IN : accountIdList]);

    for(contact cont : Trigger.new)
    {
            mapVar.get(cont.accountid).name += '-' +cont.lastname;

    }
    update mapVar.values();
}

}
```

Comment: Your modified version of this trigger still has one outstanding issue-- it will not work correctly in batches when more than one contact is added to the same account in a single trigger.

Comment: Do not use `accList` to update the accounts. Instead, update `mapVar.values()` directly.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the feedback. I updated the accList, but still couldn't figure out the more than one contact scenario. Won't the Trigger.new provide the modified Contacts inorder ?

Comment: The contacts are in order, but the problem would be that two contacts on the same account would cause two copies of that account to appear in the list of records you'd try to update, which won't work. As an aside, you could simply have written: `mapVar.get(cont.accountId).Name += '-'+cont.LastName;` instead of the three-line piece of code you have.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are right trigger is working now...thanks man...

Answer (score 1):

Variable you have used to get the last name is **con** which is not correct.

```
acct.name = mapVar.get(cont.accountid).name + '-' +con.lastname;
```

correct one is **cont**.

```
acct.name = mapVar.get(cont.accountid).name + '-' +cont.lastname;
```